# Getting Password Salt when Using Jasypt

Tags: java, encryption, salt, jasypt

I want to use Jasypt to encrypt user passwords using a random Salt. Is it possible to get random slat from Jasypt? How could I get it?

Thanks,
Feras

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a random salt is in fact the default behaviour of all jasypt encryption artifacts, and this salt is generated securely (using SHA1PRNG).

Please read http://www.jasypt.org/howtoencryptuserpasswords.html in order to know more about the way passwords are processed in jasypt.

Answer (score 0):

Never used Jasypt, but from their [documentation](http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-passwords.html):

> A salt of the specified size is generated (see org.jasypt.salt.SaltGenerator). If salt size is zero, no salt will be used. It is advisable that you use a random salt generator like org.jasypt.salt.RandomSaltGenerator (which is the default) for higher security.

you can use [RandomSaltGenerator](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.8/org/jasypt/salt/RandomSaltGenerator.html).